# Difference between vim ./test.py and test.py

Tags: linux, shell

Please help me to figure out the difference between below commands

```
cd /home/prats

vim ./test.py 

vim test.py
```

I think both are doing the same..please let me know whats the best one and the difference.

Thanks,

Comment: In Linux (and most computing environments) relative paths (`file`) are a *shorthand* for `$CWD/file`, or `./file`: `.` is by definition a synonym of $CDW, the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

These are in fact equals, as vim will always search the current working directory for the specified filename.

In general, `./test.py` expands to `$PWD/test.py` (the file test.py relative to the current working directory), while `test.py` does not. It depends on the context if that is the same.

It's a difference, for example, when executing the file. Then, the `./test.py` will ony execute the file in the current working directory, while `test.py` will search the `$PATH` for a file `test.py`, and will execute it from anywhere on the PATH. It will only execute `test.py` in the current working directory, if that itself is in the PATH (which is strongly discouraged and no longer standard since many years on most systems).